# How to log event from Android Application for App+Web google analytics Property?

Tags: android, google-analytics, google-analytics-sdk

We are asked to implement App+Web property from Google Analytics. We have gone through the documentation but it has code that helps to log event from web only. We are unable to find any code which shows how to log event from Android App for App+Web google analytics Property.

Comment: Why would you want to log an android app to web analytics property.  Your going to have to do it manually though the measurement protocol the Firebase SDK isnt going to support that it sends data to firebase analytics

Comment: @DaImTo We are supposed to consolidate events from both app and web to a single platform for our further campaigns. For this, we choose App + Web property for the same.

Or

Should we just need to log event using firebase and it will be there in Analytics??

Comment: I cant tell you how you  **should** do things.  I can just tell you that the Firebase Sdk inserts into firebase analytics. which is not Google analytics. Your website assuming you are using analytics.js is inserting into Google analytics which is not firebase analytics.  On top of that you cant analyze against two different things how do you want to compare a boat performance and a cars performance for example? You cant they are two completely unrelated things

Comment: Need to scratch my head again...

Then what is the purpose of App+Web Property in google analytics which eventually getting linked to firebase project while selecting android app...?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to utilize Firebase Analytics to send data to App + Web.

On your App + Web property, go to the Admin section, and to Data Streams. There you can link Web, iOS and Android streams. Just follow the steps.

If you already have a Firebase Analytics configured, you can link it to a App + Web property instead. All the data will be shared between the two (including past data).

For sending events, you can refer to the [Firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference?hl=en-us). It's the exact same process.

Comment: Hmm. Let me try the same. Thanks Anyway.